# 2 Wordpress Sites on 1 host; one php4 the other php5 -

Tags: wordpress, php5, installation, php

So, I have two websites setup through 1and1 hosting. One, apparently needs php4 the other apparently needs php5.

The site that is priority requires php4; the other php5. When I switch them, one of the sites break in response. The php4 site's menu is destroyed and displays code and ugly errors in it's place, the other is broken by when you attempt to 'click' anything with the Wordpress Control panel (ie; Click 'posts' and get an error 500).

**Anyone know what to do?**

Comment: If code is being displayed when you switch versions, it sounds like the PHP5 config has `short_tags` disabled while the PHP4 config has them enabled. The fix for that is to just replace `<?` with `<?php` in the code -- an easy change.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the code to work with PHP5 or put the sites on separate hosting. PHP 5 is now over 7 years old. You should not expect to be able to continue hosting that PHP 4 site anywhere much longer.

Comment: I agree with Dan above, rewrite the code or you are going to run into more problems sooner rather than later.